# XPATH expression to retrieve this informartion inside <b> </b> <br/> tags

Tags: c#, html, .net, vb.net, xpath

First of all, my knowloedges about html are less than basic.

I have this piece of an html code:

```
    <div class="main_panel_sub">
        <p>
            <p>
                <b>Genre</b>: pop<br/>
                <b>Country</b>: USA<br />
                <b>Year</b>: 2013<br />
                <b>Audio codec</b>: MP3<br />
                <b>Riptype</b>: tracks<br />
                <b>Bitrate</b>: 320 kbps<br />
                <b>Playtime</b>: 01:06:44<br />
                <b>Size:</b> 153 MB<br />
                <b>Site:</b> 
                <a href='XXXXXXX'>XXXXXXX.com</a>
            </p>
        </p>
```

I'm using the library `HTMLAgilityPack` and I would like to retrieve the `Genre` and the `Year` values, I just need to know the right XPath

This is the XPATH that I'm trying to use but I'm lost with those `<b> </b> <br/>`

```
Genre = node.SelectSingleNode("..//div[@class='main_panel_sub']/p/p/b[1]").InnerText
Year = node.SelectSingleNode("..//div[@class='main_panel_sub']/p/p/b[3]").InnerText
```

At the first line of code above I get the string `Genre` instead of the genre value `Pop`.

And with the second line I get `Year` string instead of `2013`.

> UPDATE:

A (problematic) variation DIV example:

```
<div class="main_panel_sub">
<p><p><b>Genre</b>: Synthpop<br />
<b>Year</b>: 2012<br />
<b>Audio codec</b>: MP3<br />
<b>Riptype</b>: tracks<br />
<b>Bitrate</b>: VBR~256 kbps<br />
<b>Playtime</b>: 00:29:21<br />
<b>Size:</b> 57 MB<br />
<b>Site:</b> <a href='http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com'>xxxx.com</a></p>
</p>
```

And the code that I've tried to use:

```
 Dim fields = (From field In node.SelectNodes("..//div[@class='main_panel_sub']//b")
              Let contentNodes = field.ParentNode.ChildNodes.SkipWhile(Function(e) Not e.Equals(field)).
                                 TakeWhile(Function(e) e.Equals(field) OrElse e.Name <> "b")
                                 Let content = [String].Concat(contentNodes.[Select](Function(e) e.InnerText))
                                 Select content.Split(":")).
                                        ToDictionary(Function(s) s(0).ToLower.Trim(), Function(s) s(1).Trim())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing such html is problematic since it lists the properties inconsistently.  There is no fixed pattern to all the fields.  The colons are sometimes inside the `b` tags, not all fields end with a `br` tag (which would be a good way to delimit each field.  If you have any influence on how the html is formatted, I would push for a single consistent format for every field.  Or at least put them in an unordered list or something to make selecting the fields easier to accomplish.

Basically, you will want to group all the fields with their content and parse out the groups.  Easier said than done, but doable.

```
var fields =
    (from field in node.SelectNodes("..//div[@class='main_panel_sub']//b")
    // group the nodes
    let contentNodes = field.ParentNode.ChildNodes
        .SkipWhile(e => e != field)
        .TakeWhile(e => e == field || e.Name != "b")
    // easier to parse as strings
    let content = String.Concat(contentNodes.Select(e => e.InnerText))
    select content.Split(':'))
    .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim());
var genre = fields["Genre"];
var year = fields["Year"];
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the format of the html doesn't lend itself well to stick to purely HAP methods.  You'll have to do a mix in order to accomplish what you want.

Comment: #Jeff Mercado the linq method does not work with a genre like this: `<p><p><b>Genre</b>: Synthpop<br />` please could you fix it?

Comment: In what way is it failing? If that's the way it is formatted, it isn't much different than your example in the question so it _should_ work. Could you include that as an example in your question (the full `main_panel_sub` div)? So I can see what needs to change.

Comment: I've updated my question, it throws an exception I think because the "b", I'm not using the C# version I've translated it to VB but with any modification (just I've added the s(0).Tolower)

Comment: What was the exception? I ran the same VB code you used on that snippet and it was fine for that example.